# rails scheduler daemon run task immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduler

I am using https://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon for my scheduled jobs, but I would like  jobs immediately with a command (rather than waiting for the delay specified in the task).

I've tried using `rails runner TaskName.run` but the class can never be found (`runner.rb:53:in 'eval': uninitialized constant TaskName (NameError)`).

How can I run the scheduled tasks immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, you want to call one of the scheduled task directly.

If I were you, I'd ask to the author directly, via the channel he points at in the readme: https://github.com/ssoroka/scheduler_daemon/issues

If there is a way to do it, I'm sure the author will be glad to explain it in the readme as well.

Corollary question: for a one-time schedule, do you want your direct trigger to cancel the schedule?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the scheduler to run the task for you, just call the MyTask.new.run directly.